# Структура приложения. С чего начать и какие технологии использовать?

Tags: java, android, android-studio

Давно хотелось написать приложение на Android, в котором будут составы футбольных команд топ лиг. При нажатии на эмблему клуба должен открываться состав, а при нажатии на игрока - информация о нем. Само приложение какую-то пользу в себе не несет. Хочется просто для себя это сделать.
Подскажите, что нужно использовать и как можно построить свою работу над приложением, с чего начать.

Comment: почитайте книги П.Дейтел "Android для разработчиков" и Б.Филлипс "Android. Программирование для профессионалов" обе 3-е издание. Там вы найдете всю необходимую информацию по разработке приложения на конкретных примерах разработки этих приложений.

Comment: @pavlofff Благодарю, ознакомлюсь.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Для начала вам нужно определиться с общей инфраструктурой приложения, откуда вы будете брать данные (можно поискать ресурсы, которые отдают то что вам нужно по API, можно просто парсить какой-нибудь сайт), будете ли вы их хранить, если будете, то как вы будете их обновлять. В простом случае можно найти какой-нибудь ресурс с нужными вам данными и просто каждый раз загружать их оттуда, парсить и выводить.

Можно аналогично загружать, но в локальную базу, и например раз в сутки обновлять её.

Нарисуйте хотя бы на листике макеты ваших Activity, вы же наверняка представляете как это будет выглядеть?

Разбейте на подзадачи ваше приложение, начните например с простейшего Activity, в который вы будете просто выводить строки, например названия команд. Создайте классы для сетевого взаимодействия - отправки запросов, получения данных, преобразование их в POJO.

И так далее. В этом деле главное начать с минимума, а дальше оно само пойдет, вы и не заметите как.

Answer (score 1):

Язык программирования: `Java` или `Kotlin`

Среда: `Android Studio`

Теория: `Activity`, `Fragment` - их жизненный цикл, `ConstraintLayout`, `RecyclerView` (вот отличная статья [ссылка](https://code.tutsplus.com/ru/tutorials/getting-started-with-recyclerview-and-cardview-on-android--cms-23465)), обработка событий, слушатели